# QTreeWidgetItem hierarchy to SQL

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtreeview

I would like to store the contents of a QTreeWidget into a MySQL database.

The SQL for the table description is:

```
CREATE TABLE category (
id          int not null,
parentId    int,
name        varchar(1024), );
```

Where **parentId** is a foreign key that references **id** from the same table.
(meant to perform a self join )

Using QtCreator, the following code works fine:

```
int FactsBuilder::findChildren( QTreeWidgetItem *node, int top )
{

    for( int i = 0; i < node->childCount(); ++i )
    {

       QTreeWidgetItem *item = node->child(i);
       qDebug() << "Child: " << top++ << " - "  << item->text(0);
       if(item->childCount() > 0 ) {

           this->findChildren(item, top++ );
       }
    }

    return top;
}

void FactsBuilder::updateCatSQL()
{

    int count = 1;
    for( int i = 0; i < ui->treeWidget->topLevelItemCount(); ++i )
    {

       QTreeWidgetItem *item = ui->treeWidget->topLevelItem( i );
       qDebug() << "Item Number: " << count++ <<  " - " << item->text(0);


       if(item->childCount() > 0 ) {
            count = this->findChildren( item, count);
       }
    }
}
```

some sample output:

```
Top:  1  -  "foo"
Top:  2  -  "bar"
Child:  3  -  "beer"
Child:  4  -  "ice"
Top:  5  -  "bla"
Top:  6  -  "baz"
```

The top items have no parent, so in such case, the **parentId** column in the MySQL database would contain NULL.

In this case the QTreeWidgetItems with "beer" and "ice" stored in its text attribute would result in storing "2" in the **parentId** column of the database. Because they are organized under the QTreeWidgetItem with "bar" stored in its text attribute.

First case

[image]

Except when the QTreeWidgetItems with "ice" would be organized under the QTreeWidgetItem with "beer" stored in its text attribute.

In such case I would expect a "2" and "3" in the **parentId** columns of the database.

Second case

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all if your table is designed better the solution is simplified, a better one is to make the id field that is autoincrement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category  (
    id          int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    parentId    int,
    name        varchar(1024)
)
```

Then I have created a method that receives the `invisibleRootItem()` from the `QTreeWidget` and that is saved by the information in the database.

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtSql>

static bool createConnection(){
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("hostname");
    db.setDatabaseName("databasename");
    db.setUserName("username");
    db.setPassword("password");
    if (!db.open()) {
        qDebug()<<"Cannot open database\n"
                  "Unable to establish a database connection.\n"
                  "This example needs SQLite support. Please read "
                  "the Qt SQL driver documentation for information how "
                  "to build it.\n\n"
                  "Click Cancel to exit.";
        return false;
    }
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.exec("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS category;");
    if(!query.exec(R"(CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category  (
                   id          int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                   parentId    int,
                   name        varchar(1024)
                   ))"))
        qDebug()<<query.lastError().text();
    return true;
}
static void fill_model(QTreeWidget &tree){
    QTreeWidgetItem *foo_item = new QTreeWidgetItem({"foo"});
    QTreeWidgetItem *bar_item = new QTreeWidgetItem({"bar"});
    QTreeWidgetItem *bla_item = new QTreeWidgetItem({"bla"});
    QTreeWidgetItem *baz_item = new QTreeWidgetItem({"baz"});
    for(QTreeWidgetItem *item : {foo_item, bar_item, bla_item, baz_item})
        tree.addTopLevelItem(item);
    QTreeWidgetItem *beer_item = new QTreeWidgetItem({"beer"});
    QTreeWidgetItem *beer_child_item = new QTreeWidgetItem({"beer_child"});
    QTreeWidgetItem *ice_item = new QTreeWidgetItem({"ice"});
    for(QTreeWidgetItem *item : {beer_item, ice_item})
        bar_item->addChild(item);
    beer_item->addChild(beer_child_item);
    beer_child_item->addChild(new QTreeWidgetItem({"beer_child_child"}));
}
static void save_to_db(const QString & tablename, QTreeWidgetItem* parent, int parent_id=0){
    for(int i=0; i< parent->childCount(); ++i){
        QTreeWidgetItem *child_item = parent->child(i);
        QSqlQuery query(QString("INSERT INTO %1 (parentId, name) VALUES (?, ?)").arg(tablename));
        if(parent_id != 0)
            query.bindValue(0, parent_id);
        query.bindValue(1, child_item->text(0));
        if(!query.exec())
            qDebug()<< query.lastError().text();
        save_to_db(tablename, child_item, query.lastInsertId().toInt());
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    if(!createConnection())
       return -1;
    QWidget w;
    QTreeWidget tree_widget;
    fill_model(tree_widget);
    save_to_db("category", tree_widget.invisibleRootItem());
    tree_widget.expandAll();
    QTableView table_view;
    QSqlTableModel model;
    model.setTable("category");
    model.select();
    table_view.setModel(&model);
    QHBoxLayout *hlay = new QHBoxLayout(&w);
    hlay->addWidget(&tree_widget);
    hlay->addWidget(&table_view);
    w.resize(640, 480);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where do you declare `category.parentId` as a foreign key to `category.id`?

Comment: add **FOREIGN KEY (parentId) REFERENCES category(id)** to the table description sql.

Comment: or add **ALTER TABLE category ADD CONSTRAINT fk_category FOREIGN KEY (parentId) REFERENCES category(id);** anywhere you like. (The table must exist before you do this.)

Comment: @DagmarHofman My idea is to give you the logic for how to save MySql, did my solution work?

Comment: @DagmarHofman If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it then check the [tour]